# Does pipenv download packages everytime or does it use cached packages like pip?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

If we try to install a package via pip, it uses the cached packages that we have downloaded before. Does pipenv do the same or does it download the packages every time we do `pipenv install` etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just runs pip, so it uses the pip cache.